# Background and full-screen image

Tags: c++, qt

How can I set a background and full-screen image?

I use `M_Widget->setStyleSheet("background: url(images.jpeg);background-repeat: no-repeat");`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For adding an image as the background for one widget you should do this :

```
QGridLayout *gridLayout;
QWidget     *M_widget;
gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralWidget());
gridLayout->setSpacing(0);
gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
M_widget = new QWidget(centralWidget());
M_widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("M_widget"));
M_widget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/images/images/imge1.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;"));

gridLayout->addWidget(M_widget, 0, 0, 1, 1);

showFullScreen();
```

and for showing that widget as **FullScreen you should call** `showFullScreen();` Function.

Each widget has `showFullScreen()` function but I guess you want to show Full image inside your widget because of that you should add  `0 0 0 0 stretch stretch` in your stylesheet.

```
 M_widget->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/images/images/imge1.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;"));
```